# generic types on method parameters

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

Here is the scenario:

```
public static <T> List<T> isTriggeredByBlackList(Map<String, T> params, Class<T> clz)   {
    System.out.println(clz.getName());

    return null;
}
```

What I want is to pass either `String` or `List<String>` to this method.

When it comes to `String`, it works just fine:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("11", "22");
isTriggeredByBlackList(map1, String.class);
```

But When I tried to pass a `List<String>`, it goes wrong:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("11");
l.add("22");
map.put("1", l);
isTriggeredByBlackList(map, List.class);    //compile error!
```

With compile error as below:

```
The method isTriggeredByBlackList(Map<String,T>, Class<T>) in the type CommonTest is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,List<String>>, Class<List>)
```

What I need is to **write just one method which is suitable to both `String` type as well as `List<String>` type.**

Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the signature of your method:

```
public static <T> List<T> isTriggeredByBlackList(Map<String, ? extends T> params, Class<T> clz)
```

**Why does this work?**

The expression `? extends T` just means that any type that is a subtype of `T` (and of course `T` itself) is accepted.

[What is a wildcard?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20is%20a%20wildcard?)

So when method `isTriggeredByBlackList` is called like that:

```
isTriggeredByBlackList(map, List.class);
```

... `T` is specified to be a (raw) `List` type, and so the first parameter must be a `Map<String, any-type-that-extends-raw-List>`, which is true for `Map<String, List<String>>` (because `List<String>` is a subtype of (raw) `List`).

---

**But why is a List a subtype of (raw) List?**

Generics are tricky, because polymorphism does not work as expected (on the first sight). A `List<String>` *is-NOT-a* `List<Object>`, although `String` extends `Object`! So this won't work:

```
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<String>(); // compile error
```

(Note: It's good that this is not possible, but that's another story)

But a `List<String>` *IS-a* (raw) `List` (and it *is-a* `List<?>`). So this works:

```
List rawList = new ArrayList<String>(); // just compiler warning
List<?> unknownList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The reason is: Raw types are still supported to be backwards-compatible! Otherwise old code that does not support generics could not be used nowadays. So any instance of a concrete parametrized type (e.g. `ArrayList<String>`) can be assigned to a reference of its raw type (e.g. `ArrayList`) or super types (e.g. `List`)!

[Why are raw types permitted?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ202)

**Why can't we pass something like `List<String>.class`?**

Because parameterized types have no exact runtime type representation!

[Why is there no class literal for concrete parameterized types?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ105)

**But I want to get a `List<List<String>>` as return value!**

This is no problem! Just define the left side of your assignment to be a `List<List<String>>`, and java does the rest:

```
List<List<String>> l = isTriggeredByBlackList(map, List.class);
```

BUT! This only works, if you slightly modify your method declaration:

```
public static <T> List<T> isTriggeredByBlackList(
    Map<String, ? extends T> params, Class<? super T> clz)
```

(Otherwise you can't pass the raw `List.class` as second argument).

---

If all this modifications and tweaks make sense depends on the task your method should fulfill! Is it only reading from `params`? How does it make use of the generic type arguments? What is the advantage of using generics here? etc.

---

Btw.: Methods that start with `is...` should return a `boolean` value. Consider renaming your method!
Btw 2.: The return type of your method is `List<T>`, so in case you're specifying `T` to be a `List`, you'll get a `List<List>`. Is this intended?

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine. But could you explain more deeply on the `? extends T` syntax? As you can see, My param is a `List<String>`, and I use `List.class`, I don't see where the point is.

Comment: @SteveP List<String> does not extend List. so explanation is not correct.

Comment: @ShyamendraSolanki True, do you have an explanation for it?

Comment: @isnot2bad Crap, I deleted my comment.  Could you edit your answer so OP sees the reasoning?

Comment: @Judking can you assign the result of `isTriggeredByBlackList` to a List<String> ? It does not work for me.

Comment: @ShyamendraSolanki That was not what the question was about! Of course you can't assign the result to a List<String>, because T is a List, so the return parameter is List<List>.

Comment: @isnot2bad I imagine that he wants a return type of `List<List<T>>`.  Is that possible with given that he's passing `T` as `List`, the raw type?

Comment: Your explanation helps. But OP's point was he wants `String` or `List<String>` but this code allows `List<Integer>` etc.

Comment: @ShyamendraSolanki If that's the case, then he should just overload.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Here's another problem: I've tried overloading with no success. because Map<String, String> and Map<String, List<String>> will be erased to the same type Map, So I cannot assign these two parameters to two method with the same name. Is there any solution to this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 related points here, with this code.

```
public static <T> List<T> isTriggeredByBlackList(Map<String, T> params, Class<T> clz)   {
    System.out.println(clz.getName());

    return null;
}
```

1) The requirement is to support only `String` or `List<String>` as parameter in map value. 
   That is not possible to meet in single (Generic) method.
   It will require overloaded methods (as Steve P. mentioned) instead of Generic.

2) If we relax that and use generic method. Then the above definition can be used as it is, if we change the map's type.

```
Map<String, List> m = new HashMap<String, List>(); // The Raw List.

isTriggeredByBlackList(m, List.class);
```

3) If the method signature is changed to:

```
static <T> List<T> isTriggeredByBlackList(Map<String, ? extends T> params, Class<T> clz)
```

As @isnot2bad has explained quite well, it accepts all Lists as in case of #2.

Comment: I like point 1 most: Instead of struggling around with generics, maybe two simple, non-generic methods are sufficient! But as so often it depends on what the method should do.

Comment: As you said, I've tried overloading with no success. because `Map<String, String>` and `Map<String, List<String>>` will be erased to the same type `Map`, So I cannot assign these two parameters to two method with the same name. Is there any solution to this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Question is the same as above. @isnot2bad